# disable text highlight on mouse over using css

Tags: css

I want my text on the button to be not highlighted when the mouse pointer is moved over it.

i tried applying the following which didnt work.

```
background-color:transparent;
opacity:1;
```

someone, please let me know the style to be applied.
Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: what did you tried so far? can you represent us a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please can you add you full css of your hover and none hover states (with the full selectors)

Comment: `background-color` doesn't do anything with text and `opacity: 1` is default, so the things you tried don't really make sense

Comment: I Don't cath the issue but maybe if is user-select what you want to disable try [THIS SOLUTION](http://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/2887133)

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (example):

Normal: (highlighted)

```
a{
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Hovered (not highlighted)

```
a:hover{
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of what you can do:

```
#ID {
    background-color:yellow;
}

#ID:hover{
    background-color:white;
}
```

This will cause the text in the html element with id `ID` to be highlighted UNLESS the mouse is hovering over the text.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1e3me57/) with the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

On you :hover code snippet set the color of the text to what you want it to appear as. For example:

```
#element a{
    color: black;
}

#element a:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

Remember that to change the colour of the text you have to use color, not background-color.